# Error while running Node application with Docker: db-on-docker@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have developed a `Nodejs` application with `Docker` but when I run the application I get the error:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/index.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! db-on-docker@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the db-on-docker@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-30T05_34_13_500Z-debug.log
```

Following are my files:
`DockerFile` present within `web` folder:

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["npm","start"]

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Following is my `docker-compose.yml` file present within my `root project folder`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
      DATABASE_HOST: localhost
    restart: always

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: node:8
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
    environment: ["project=${project}", "type=${type}"]
```

I did the following things:

1. `docker-compose build -d` to load all images.
2. `docker-comoise up -d` to bring-up all the images and confirmed the same using `docker-compose ps`.
3. Then ran the application using the command `docker-compose exec web sh -c "project=myproject type=New npm start"`

When I run the 3rd step I get the error as provided above. This was working previously when I developed the application. Now I am trying to run the same application in another system but getting this error. Unable to follow what might be wrong.

I have added the `express using npm install` so I guess its not due to that but due to the line `npm ERR! Failed at the db-on-docker@1.0.0 start script.`, I tried to install `express` using `npm install --save express`, deleted the `node_modules` folder. Tried the `npm install` but nothing seems to work for me.

Can someone please let me know what I need to do?

Comment: do a npm install -g express

Comment: how is defined the "start" script? for testing, try just: **CMD npm start**

Comment: @Satya Thanks a lot for the response. I tried this but still running into the same issue. Can you please suggest some alternative.

Comment: @a_e Thanks a lot for the response. Actually, the code was developed by another developer so I am not entirely sure how is `start script` defined as I am new to `docker and node js. I tried running `npm start` but that is not working and getting error `missing script "start"`. Can you please assist me with this issue?

Comment: since there is not start script, then just start with: **CMD node index.js**

Comment: Often you can get inconsistent results if you use `volumes:` to overwrite the image's code with something else.  The `RUN npm install` in the Dockerfile is completely hidden by the `volumes:` mount in the Compose setup.  Does deleting the `volumes:` block help at all?  (Also delete all of the `tail -f /dev/null` lines, so `docker-compose up` will actually start your service.)

Answer (score 0):

There is one thins missing there in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

You don't tell docker to build your `Dockerfile`, instead, just grab the image `node:8` from docker registry, but how does docker know that you need to install your packages?

You have to add this block under `web` service in `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
build:
      context: ./web
```

One more thing to mention is that, you're overriding the default command that you declared in `Dockerfile`, you can remove this line from `docker-compose.yml` file

```
command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

Honestly, I don't know why you need this here.

You can also try to remove this instruction from `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

I think `npm start` is enough

> **Note**: `npm start` requires that you define the entry point in your `package.json` file, otherwise, you will get an error

One lat thing and back you the error you've mentioned herewith in your question:

**The reason** is because the container can't find `express` module installed inside the image you're using `node:8` in this case, because you just use the image and map your project directory to the container without installing the dependencies.